# How to retrieve DateTime from MySQL without milliseconds using JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

After I retrieve `java.util.Date` from MySQL table I have the following Date in my JSP view `2015-10-08 01:26:24.0`. It shows milliseconds. How can I get rid off them? There are no milliseconds in table`2015-10-07 19:24:39` Here is my Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Payment {
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date paymentDate;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        paymentDate  = new Date();
    }
}
```

In view

```
<c:out value="${payment.paymentDate}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is nothing related to JPA. This can be achieved in many ways, one is to apply SimpleDateFormat (as @hermitmaster suggested) to your date object, or you can apply formatting on your JSP page using [JSTL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatdate_tag.htm).

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
...
<fmt:formatDate type="both" value="${payment.paymentDate}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a convenience method that applies a SimpleDateFormat and returns the result.